# Is it possible to configure .angular/cache folder location to somewhere out of the project folder?

Tags: angular, webpack

It is true, that .angular/cache folder location is convenient in many cases in the project folder root, however sometimes it is not. For example if I execute file/content search from the project root it always must be excluded to speed up the search process.

Is it possible to configure .angular/cache folder location to somewhere out of the project folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
ng config cli.cache.path "my path"
```

this creates a configuration entry in angular.json:

```
{
  ...
  "cli": {
    "cache": {
      "path": "my path"
    },
  },
  ...
}
```